# iOS 7 Back Button in Interface builder

Tags: interface-builder, ios7

I've been messing around with the new iOS7 SDK and I want to make a back button like there is in most of the other OS apps. Heres a screen shot of what I'm trying to do:
[image: What I'm trying to create]

But I can't figure out how. I've never really messed with interface builder because I usually code with opengl apps, so any solutions would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @Kevin No, the actual button itself

Comment: try messing around with UIBarButtonItem or creating a UINavigationController and having the base view controller set to 'September' as the title

Comment: @user2277872 I've tried messing around with the BarButton, and the navigation controller's title is the thing in the middle of the bar.

Comment: so are you trying to create a button that looks the way the above image does, or are you trying to create a button with the same tint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is is standard "back" button. You get this when you use a navigation controller and show one view controller then push a second. The "<" means "go back". The "September" part is the title of the previous view controller. You don't need to create one of these. Just make proper use of a navigation controller and a couple of view controllers and it will appear automatically.

Comment: How exactly do I use a Navigation view controller, like I said, I usuall don't mess with this stuff. EDIT: For future reference, you make a view controller and then in there you need to use a push transition to get to another view, then the back button will appear.